# How does stringstream work with <<?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I am trying to use `<<` as a means of moving integers into a stringstream.  There must be something fundamental and basic I am overlooking. The simplest of code does not even compile:

```
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "simple test ";
```

produces this error:

> error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char [13]'

Comment: We need more code than this.

Comment: [That should compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e80e8a9f45ac50c6)

Comment: Depends. What is "stromgstream"?

Comment: @Borgleader: That is not the code the OP posted.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a valid C++ program.

First, you need to include `sstream`. Then, you need to put that expression with `<<` into a *function*.

Like this:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "simple test ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    string s;

    ss << "simple test ";

    s = ss.str();

    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```